# jQuery stop tooltip plugin displaying html

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, tooltip

I would like my tooltip to stop displaying rendered HTML and the mark up instead. I noticed for displaying data in i.e. a  repeater the following works fine. Using jQuery Tooltip plugin 1.3.

```
Server.HtmlEncode(Eval("ActivityDescription") as string)
```

And then I thought I could do the same for title attribute

```
<td class="activityDescriptionTooltip" title="<%# Server.HtmlEncode(Eval("ActivityDescription") as string) %>">
<%# Utilities.TruncateAtWord(Server.HtmlEncode(Eval("ActivityDescription") as string),30) %>
</td>
```

Tooltip called like this via plugin

```
   $j('.activityDescriptionTooltip').tooltip();
```

So if my ActicvityDescription is  `"<h2>Test</h2>"`

I want to see `"<h2>Test</h2>"` in the tooltip. My title attribute renders as

```
title="&amp;lt;h2&amp;gt;Test&amp;lt;/h2&amp;gt;"
```

But in the tooltip it renders as just "Test" with H2 formatting.

Is this possible ?

Comment: You may need to replace these characters with `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

Comment: Server.HtmlEncode does this tho so i.e. my title attribute renders as title="&amp;lt;h2&amp;gt;Test&amp;lt;/h2&amp;gt; yup" but it shows just "Test" in h2 markup my tooltip

Comment: How is this connected to jQuery? Are you using some kind of a jQuery tooltip plugin? If yes can you share what plugin it is?

Comment: Yup sorry jQuery Tooltip plugin 1.3

Comment: Why would you use that? Anyway I updated my answer, again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, not only it is possible, but it should work just the same as in the "repeater".

The function you used ([Server.HTMLEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525347%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)) is perfect for this.

The following should work fine

```
<td class="activityDescriptionTooltip" title="<%# Server.HtmlEncode("<h2>Test</h2>") %>">
```

The problem with your code is that you encode the string twice (therefore the tooltip will show the encoded string).

Instead of this:

```
<td class="activityDescriptionTooltip" title="<%# Server.HtmlEncode(Server.HtmlEncode(Eval("ActivityDescription") as string)) %>">
```

Try this:

```
<td class="activityDescriptionTooltip" title="<%# Server.HtmlEncode(Eval("ActivityDescription") as string) %>">
```

---

**EDIT**:

You stated that this does not work. I think it does.

Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Befpm/). As you can see the html is:

```
<div title="&lt;h2&gt;Test&lt;/h2&gt;">asdf</div>
```

And if you hover over the div in the down-right (result) frame, the tooltip shows `<h2>Test</h2>` just fine. In IE10, FF and Chrome at least. (I haven't tried other browsers, but I would be completely stunned if they worked differently in this matter).

---

**EDIT2**:

The [jQuery tooltip plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/) is a very old and outdated plugin, which does require one extra level of encoding:

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Befpm/2/)

```
<div title="&amp;lt;i&amp;gt;Test&amp;lt;/i&amp;gt;">asdf</div>
```

It is encoded twice and shows up just fine.

On the other hand I do not recommend that plugin. The [jQuery UI Tooltip](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/) would be a better choice for you.

Comment: But from my example you can see thats I have, and in the tooltip it renders as "Test" with h2 formatting and not "<h2>Test</h2>"

Comment: Sorry that double encoding was just something I tried, its the same affect without it

Comment: The encoding works and my title attribute is "&lt;h2&gt;Test&lt;/h2&gt;" but for some reason the tooltip renders it as HTML

Comment: You are mistaken. It works if your title attirbute is `title="&lt;h2&gt;Test&lt;/h2&gt;"`. Just check the example in the edit part of my answer.

Comment: Aye I see your fiddle, and for just displaying title it works fine. But my issue is with this not working with Jquery Tooltip plugin which picks up from the Title attribute

Comment: Hey Soondead thanks for your help ! How would I achieve this double encoding ? I tried <%# Server.HtmlEncode(Server.HtmlEncode(Eval("ActivityDescription") as string)) %> But it was still as normal

Comment: `<%# Server.HtmlEncode(Server.HtmlEncode(Eval("ActivityDescription") as string)) %>` should do it. If you get the same html as in my second edit, it should work fine.